# ASP.NET OAuth Authorization - Difference between using ClientId and Secret and Username and Password

Tags: asp.net, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to implement a simple `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` in ASP.NET WebAPI 2. My main purpose is to learn how to have a token for a mobile app. I would like users to login with username & password, and then receive a token (and a refresh token so they won't have to re-enter credentials once token expires). Later on, I would like to have the chance to open the API for external use by other applications (like one uses Facebook api and such...).

Here is how I've set-up my AuthorizationServer:

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(new SimpleAuthorizationServerProviderOptions()
    {
        ValidateUserCredentialsFunction = ValidateUser
    }),
    RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
});
```

This is my `SimpleAuthorizationServerProviderOptions` implementation:

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public delegate Task<bool> ClientCredentialsValidationFunction(string clientid, string secret);
    public delegate Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> UserCredentialValidationFunction(string username, string password);
    public SimpleAuthorizationServerProviderOptions Options { get; private set; }

    public SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(SimpleAuthorizationServerProviderOptions options)
    {
        if (options.ValidateUserCredentialsFunction == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("ValidateUserCredentialsFunction cannot be null");
        }
        Options = options;
    }

    public SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(UserCredentialValidationFunction userCredentialValidationFunction)
    {
        Options = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProviderOptions()
        {
            ValidateUserCredentialsFunction = userCredentialValidationFunction
        };
    }

    public SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(UserCredentialValidationFunction userCredentialValidationFunction, ClientCredentialsValidationFunction clientCredentialsValidationFunction)
    {
        Options = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProviderOptions()
        {
            ValidateUserCredentialsFunction = userCredentialValidationFunction,
            ValidateClientCredentialsFunction = clientCredentialsValidationFunction
        };
    }

    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        if (Options.ValidateClientCredentialsFunction != null)
        {
            string clientId, clientSecret;

            if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
            {
                context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);
            }

            var clientValidated = await Options.ValidateClientCredentialsFunction(clientId, clientSecret);
            if (!clientValidated)
            {
                context.Rejected();
                return;
            }
        }

        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        if (Options.ValidateUserCredentialsFunction == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("ValidateUserCredentialsFunction cannot be null");
        }

        var claims = await Options.ValidateUserCredentialsFunction(context.UserName, context.Password);
        if (claims == null)
        {
            context.Rejected();
            return;
        }

        // create identity
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Options.AuthenticationType);

        // create metadata to pass to refresh token provider
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "as:client_id", context.UserName }
        });

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
        context.Validated(ticket);
    }

    public override async Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
    {
        var originalClient = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];
        var currentClient = context.ClientId;

        // enforce client binding of refresh token
        if (originalClient != currentClient)
        {
            context.Rejected();
            return;
        }

        // chance to change authentication ticket for refresh token requests
        var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Ticket.Identity);
        newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("newClaim", "refreshToken"));

        var newTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(newIdentity, context.Ticket.Properties);
        context.Validated(newTicket);
    }
}
```

And my `SimpleRefreshTokenProvider` implementation:

```
public class SimpleRefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket> _refreshTokens =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket>(); 

    public void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {

    }

    public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var refreshTokenProperties = new AuthenticationProperties(context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            IssuedUtc = context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1)
        };
        var refreshTokenTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(context.Ticket.Identity, refreshTokenProperties);

        _refreshTokens.TryAdd(guid, refreshTokenTicket);
        context.SetToken(guid);
    }

    public void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {

    }

    public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        AuthenticationTicket ticket;
        if (_refreshTokens.TryRemove(context.Token, out ticket))
        {
            context.SetTicket(ticket);
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't fully understand is the use of `ClientId and Secret` vs `Username and Password`. The code I pasted generates a token by username and password and I can work with that token (until it expires), but when I try to get a refresh token, I must have the ClientId.

Also, if a token expires, the correct way is to send the refresh token and get a new token? What if the refresh token gets stolen? isn't it the same as a username & password getting stolen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I don't fully understand is the use of `ClientId and Secret` vs `Username and Password`. The code I pasted generates a token by username and password and I can work with that token (until it expires), but when I try to get a refresh token, I must have the ClientId.
>
> Also, if a token expires, the correct way is to send the refresh token and get a new token? What if the refresh token gets stolen? isn't it the same as a username & password getting stolen?

In OAuth2 is essential to authenticate both the user and the client in any authorization flow defined by the protocol. The client authentication (as you may guess) enforces the use of your API only by known clients. The serialized access token, once generated, is not bound to a specific client directly. Please note that the `ClientSecret` must be treated as a confidential information, and can be used only by clients that can store this information in some secure way (e.g. external services clients, but not javascript clients).

The refresh token is simply an alternative "grant type" for OAuth2, and, as you stated correctly, will substitute the username and password pair for a User. This token must be treated as confidential data (even more confidential than the access token), but gives advantages over storing the username & password on the client:

- it can be revoked by the user if compromised;
- it has a limited lifetime (usually days or weeks);
- it does not expose user credentials (an attacker can only get access tokens for the "scope" the refresh token was issued).

I suggest you to read more about the different grant types defined in OAuth 2 checking in the [official draft](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4). I also recommend you [this resource](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/) I found very useful when firstly implemented OAuth2 in Web API myself.

**Sample requests**

Here are two request examples using fiddler, for `Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant`:

[image: Fiddler Request: Resource Owner Grant]

and for `Refresh Token Grant`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Also found this useful article: http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/15/adding-refresh-tokens-to-a-web-api-v2-authorization-server/

Comment: Everything from leastprivilege is golden. If in future you will need a complete OAuth2 and OpenID implementation I can only recommend you to give [IdentityServer](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/) a try.

Comment: Another question... if I understand correctly, even for a simple implementation, I will need to have at least one "client" (myself) - so I now need to validate the client and then the user? in 2 different calls to the server? or can I send the username & password along with clientid and secret?

Comment: You are correct, at least one client is required, the owin Middleware will validate client and user credentials automatically on each token request (internally it calls ValidateClientAuthentication and if valid it will call the correct validation for the chosen grant type).

Comment: Can you show me a demonstration of what I need to put in fiddler to make this happen?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just edited the answer and included two basic examples.